# Contact Form loaded with Ajax

Tags: plugins, ajax

I'm loading [Contact Form plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-plugin/) with an Ajax request. It is correctly loaded, but when trying to submit the form, I get a blank page with a 0 as unique response. I'm guessing it has something to do with the Event Handler, but don't know how to solve it. Any idea? This is my ajax code in `functions.php` (here I'm omitting the contact-page template call in Ajax callback, because it works):

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mi-script-ajax',get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/ajax-search.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'mi-script-ajax', 'MyAjax', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

function ajax_callback() {  
//Submenu
echo '<div id="submenu">';
if( $sPostType !== '' ) {
    if( $sPostType == -1 ) {
        $allCategories = get_categories();
        foreach( $allCategories as $cat ) {
            echo '<li class="type-category"><a href="' . get_permalink( $cat->cat_ID ) . '">' . $cat->name . '</a></li>'; 
        }
    } else {

        global $wpdb;
        // set the target relationship here
        $post_type = $sPostType;
        $taxonomy = 'category';

        $terms_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
            SELECT
                tt.term_id
            FROM
                {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr,
                {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt,
                {$wpdb->posts} p
            WHERE 1=1
                AND tr.object_id = p.id
                AND p.post_type = '%s'
                AND p.post_status = 'publish'
                AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
                AND tt.taxonomy ='%s'
            ", $post_type, $taxonomy ) );

        $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
            'include' => $terms_ids,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        ) );


         //$aTypeCategories = get_categories( array( 'post_type' => $type, 'number' => '10'  ) );
         foreach( $terms as $cat ) {
            echo '<li class="type-category"><a href="' . get_permalink( $cat->term_id ) . '">' . $cat->name . '</a></li>'; 
         }
    }
} else {
    echo '<li class="type-category" style="color: transparent">Sin categorías</li>'; 
}
echo '</div>';
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax', 'ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax', 'ajax_callback');
```

This is the full `ajax_callback` function:

```
function ajax_callback() {
    $pageId = 0;
    $newSlug = '';
    $reviewSlug = '';
    $sPostType = '';
    $sTemplatePart = '';

    //Links
    if( isset(  $_POST['href'] ) ) {
        $pageId = preg_match( '/^http:\/\/.+\/\?page_id=\d+$/', $_POST['href'] ) ? substr( strrchr( $_POST['href'], '=' ), 1 ) : 'no-page' ;
        if( $pageId === 'no-page' && preg_match( '/^http:\/\/.+\/\?(news|reviews|entrevistas|radio_shows)=.+$/', $_POST['href'] ) ) {
            $newSlug = substr( strrchr( $_POST['href'], '=' ), 1 );
        }
        //$pageName = get_page_template_slug( intval( $pageId ) );
        if( $pageId !== 'no-page' ) {
            if( $pageId === '8' ) {
                $sPostType = -1;
                $sTemplatePart = 'home-ajax';
            } elseif( $pageId === '22' ) { 
                $sPostType = 'reviews';
                $sTemplatePart = 'reviews-rvw-ajax';
            } elseif( $pageId === '6' ) {
                $sPostType = 'news';
                $sTemplatePart = 'noticias-news-ajax';
            } elseif( $pageId === '109' ) {
                $sPostType = 'entrevistas';
                $sTemplatePart = 'entrevistas-ajax';
            } elseif( $pageId === '112' ) {
                $sPostType = 'radio-shows';
                $sTemplatePart = 'radio-shows-ajax';
            } elseif( $pageId === '412' ) {
                $sTemplatePart = 'podcasts-ajax';
            } elseif( $pageId === '415' ) {
                $sTemplatePart = 'contacto-ajax';
            }

        } elseif( $newSlug !== '' ) {
            if( preg_match( '/^http:\/\/.+\/\?news=.+$/', $_POST['href'] ) ) {
                 $post_type = 'news';
            } elseif( preg_match( '/^http:\/\/.+\/\?reviews=.+$/', $_POST['href'] ) ) {
                 $post_type = 'reviews';
            } elseif( preg_match( '/^http:\/\/.+\/\?entrevistas=.+$/', $_POST['href'] ) ) {
                 $post_type = 'entrevistas';
            } elseif( preg_match( '/^http:\/\/.+\/\?radio_shows=.+$/', $_POST['href'] ) ) {
                 $post_type = 'radio_shows';
            } elseif( preg_match( '/^http:\/\/.+\/\?podcasts=.+$/', $_POST['href'] ) ) {
                 $post_type = 'podcasts';
            } else {
                //die();
            }
            $sTemplatePart = 'single-ajax';
            //get_template_part( 'single-ajax' );
        }

    //Siguiente y Anterior
    } elseif( isset( $_POST['cadenaAll'] ) && ( isset( $_POST['cadenaPrev'] ) || isset( $_POST['cadenaNext'] ) ) ) {
        if( isset(  $_POST['pageName'] ) ) {
            if( $_POST['pageName'] === 'reviews' ) {
                $sPostType = 'reviews';
                $sTemplatePart = 'next_reviews-rvw-ajax';
            }
            elseif( $_POST['pageName'] === 'news' ) {
                $sPostType = 'news';
                $sTemplatePart = 'next_noticias-news-ajax';
            }
            elseif( $_POST['pageName'] === 'entrevistas' ) {
                $sPostType = 'entrevistas';
                $sTemplatePart = 'next_entrevistas-ajax';
            }
            elseif( $_POST['pageName'] === 'radio_shows' ) {
                $sPostType = 'radio-shows';
                $sTemplatePart = 'radio-shows-ajax';
            }
            elseif( $_POST['pageName'] === 'radio_shows' ) {
                $sPostType = 'podcasts';
                $sTemplatePart = 'podcasts-ajax';
            }
        }
    }


    //Submenu
    echo '<div id="submenu">';
    if( $sPostType !== '' ) {
        if( $sPostType == -1 ) {
            $allCategories = get_categories();
            foreach( $allCategories as $cat ) {
                echo '<li class="type-category"><a href="' . get_permalink( $cat->cat_ID ) . '">' . $cat->name . '</a></li>'; 
            }
        } else {

            global $wpdb;
            // set the target relationship here
            $post_type = $sPostType;
            $taxonomy = 'category';

            $terms_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
                SELECT
                    tt.term_id
                FROM
                    {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr,
                    {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt,
                    {$wpdb->posts} p
                WHERE 1=1
                    AND tr.object_id = p.id
                    AND p.post_type = '%s'
                    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
                    AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
                    AND tt.taxonomy ='%s'
                ", $post_type, $taxonomy ) );

            $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
                'include' => $terms_ids,
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            ) );


             foreach( $terms as $cat ) {
                echo '<li class="type-category"><a href="' . get_permalink( $cat->term_id ) . '">' . $cat->name . '</a></li>'; 
             }
        }
    } else {
        echo '<li class="type-category" style="color: transparent">Sin categorías</li>'; 
    }
    echo '</div>';
    if( $sTemplatePart ) get_template_part($sTemplatePart);
}
```

And this is the Ajax code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


    var linksPages = $('.menu-menu-container a');

    linksPages.on('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery.post(MyAjax.url, {action : 'ajax' ,href : $(this).attr('href') }, function(response) {
                $('#content').addClass('cortinaOut');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#content').html(response).fadeIn();
                    $('#content').removeClass('cortinaOut');
                }, 500);
            });
    });

    var linksPost = $('a:not(".rpswNamePrev_2, .rpswNameNext_2, .no-ajax")')
    linksPost.live('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery.post(MyAjax.url, {action : 'ajax' ,href : $(this).attr('href') }, function(response) {
                $('#content').addClass('cortinaOut');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#content').html(response).fadeIn();
                    $('#content').removeClass('cortinaOut');
                }, 500);
            });
    });


    var cadenaNext='';
    var cadenaPrev='';
    $('#ajax-form-next, .ajax-form-num').live('submit',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery.post(MyAjax.url, {action : 'ajax' ,cadenaNext : $(this).find('.nextPosts').val(), cadenaAll : $(this).find('.allPosts').val(), pageName : $(this).find('.pageName').val(), numPage : $(this).find('.numPage').val() }, function(response) {
                $('#content').addClass('cortinaOut');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#content').html(response).fadeIn();
                    $('#content').removeClass('cortinaOut');
                }, 500);
            });
    });

    $('#ajax-form-prev').live('submit',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery.post(MyAjax.url, {action : 'ajax' ,cadenaNext : $(this).find('.prevPosts').val(), cadenaAll : $(this).find('.allPosts').val(), pageName : $(this).find('.pageName').val(), numPage : $(this).find('.numPage').val() }, function(response) {
                $('#content').addClass('cortinaOut');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#content').html(response).fadeIn();
                    $('#content').removeClass('cortinaOut');
                }, 500);
            });
    });


});
```

Comment: Firstly, You should add `die()`/`exit()` at the end of `ajax_callback`. That way 0 won't be returned. I don't see any problem with this code. But I would sure check by echoing some data like "hello world" first. If that works maybe your database query aren't returning anything.

Comment: Please post your JavaScript ajax code as well.
`0` response mostly the common problem and it cause when your action parameter of POST/GET on JavaScript is not declared or not same as `wp_ajax_action` or `wp_ajax_nopriv_action`.

Comment: @RahilWazir - Done

Comment: @ManoloSalsas You posted the same extended code. I said please show us your code for javascript ajax call.

Comment: @RahilWazir - Oh! Sorry. Here it is.

Comment: @RahilWazir - Any idea?